# OnClick, show div, then jump to the correct position

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

**Hi,**

I try to show a div on click and then jump to its position but can´t get the onClick event to work?

Pleas have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/ZsKHt/

**BestRegards**

Comment: `$(#reply)` should be `$('#reply')` in quotes, and you need to switch the jsfiddle select box on the left from Mootools to jQuery.  Then click Run at the top and it will work.

Comment: Sorry for that, Thanks alot! If you could place this as an answer, I will grant it.

Comment: I think it's better if you close the question, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(#reply) should be $('#reply') in quotes, and you need to switch the jsfiddle select box on the left from Mootools to jQuery. Then click Run at the top and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Let me fix that for you (note the 's in the ID selector):

```
<a onclick="$('#reply').css('display', 'block');" href="#contactMail">
    <div title="Maila annonsören">Test</div>
</a>
```